# Android DDMS in Titanium not starting Memory Heap

Tags: android, titanium, heap-memory, ddms

I am running Titanium Studio (based on Aptana Studio) to develop a Titanium based Android app.  When I try to analyze the memory heap in Titanium by opening the "Heap" tab, in the DDMS, I get the following message with no other results:

Could not create the view: org/jfree/experimental/swt/SWTUtils

I get a similar message when I try to open the "System Information" tab (Could not create the view: org/jfree/experimental/chart/swt/ChartComposite).  What could be the problem?

Comment: Apparently, this is a recently discovered bug in SDK r22 - the solution is to manually DL the latest stable build of r21, and copy the monitor folder from there:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55394

Comment: Just a friendly little update: with the release of SDK 22.01, this issue is now fixed

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue I had to manually update my eclipse ADT plugin. I figured that if I selected "Check for software updates" that it would have queried for the newest ADT plugin, which it didnt. From what I can tell Android Developer Tools version of eclipse has issues with the ADT plugin and the graphing controls (For memory heap view, system info view in DDMS)

source: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

> Download the ADT Plugin
>
> Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
>
> Click Add, in the top-right corner.
>
> In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the >following URL for the Location:
>
> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
>
> Click OK.

I also updated Android Developer Tools in SDK manager, but I believe manually updating the ADT plugin resolved my issue.